# Ionic - Limits of what can be pushed into [innerHTML]

Tags: ionic-framework, innerhtml, ion-checkbox

I'm a volunteer at a Coffee Shop.  I've built an app that presents the drink recipe to the barista.  Here's a quick snapshot:

[image]

The data come from a firebase realtime database.  Here's a snippet from that database:

[image]

What I want to do is to put some HTML into the instructions to format it for easy reading.  I do that by binding the content in the template file to [innerHTML] as shown below:

```
 <ion-item>
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row *ngIf="!item.temperature">
              <ion-col>
                <ion-label><strong>Instructions</strong></ion-label>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col>
                <h5 *ngIf="this.compactMode">
                  <span [innerHTML]="item.instructions"></span>
                </h5>
                <span *ngIf="!this.compactMode" [innerHTML]="item.instructions">
                </span>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col *ngIf="item.image"
                ><ion-img
                  (click)="onClickImage(item.image)"
                  src="{{item.image}}"
                ></ion-img
              ></ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
        </ion-item>
```

**THE PROBLEM**
This works really well for `<b> <ol> <ul> <li> <br>` and so on.  But it does not work for `<ion-checkbox>` nor `<input type="checkbox">`  The input tags get filtered out somewhere before being presented.

**SECURITY**
I'm aware that putting HTML into a database can increase my security surface, so I'm using *sanitizer* to filter the HTML and then I attempt to add the  after the fact.  Here's how I do it:

```
  stringFormat(inputString: string) {
    const re1 = /\[\]/gi;
    let returnString = this.sanitizer.sanitize(1, inputString);
    returnString = returnString.replace(re1, '<ion-checkbox id=\'input\'></ion-checkbox>');
    return returnString;
  }
```

You'll notice that I first sanitize the string, and then I do a substitution, replacing `[]` with the checkbox.

*(In case you're interested, I'm just making a opening/closing checklist and it would be nice if people could touch the checkbox after they've completed a task... I don't plan to store the checkbox values, I just want the checkbox user experience.)*

I have checked that item.instructions in fact includes the substituted string in the item object, but when rendered by ionic/angular, the actual text seems to have filtered out anything but vanilla HTML tags.

**Finally the Question**
So here's the question:  Are there some sort of limits to what can be inserted into the DOM using [innerHTML] binding?  Am I overthinking this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML, **I've concluded that there really is not a safe way to do this** using the approach suggested above.

Instead of embedding HTML in the database, I'm going to set up an array of paragraphs in the `item.instructions` fields of the database.  Each element in the array can have a key:value pair to indicate if the element represents a plain paragraph, or a checkbox.

[image]

Then I can iterate through the array of instructions (`*ngFor`), and for each instruction I can check the instruction type (`<div *ngIf="item.type===...>`) to determine whether to wrap the text with an `<ion-text>` or an `<ion-checkbox>`.